# Running an example script using the github.com/mgutz/dat library

Tags: postgresql, go

For historical reasons, I'm trying to run a simplified example script using [`github.com/mgutz/dat`](https://github.com/mgutz/dat), a Postgres data access toolkit. I've tried copying the example script in this repo, https://github.com/kurtpeek/postgres-update, with the following `main.go`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "time"

    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    "gopkg.in/mgutz/dat.v1"
    runner "gopkg.in/mgutz/dat.v1/sqlx-runner"
)

// global database (pooling provided by SQL driver)
var DB *runner.DB

func init() {
    // create a normal database connection through database/sql
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "dbname=dat_test user=dat password=!test host=localhost sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // ensures the database can be pinged with an exponential backoff (15 min)
    runner.MustPing(db)

    // set to reasonable values for production
    db.SetMaxIdleConns(4)
    db.SetMaxOpenConns(16)

    // set this to enable interpolation
    dat.EnableInterpolation = true

    // set to check things like sessions closing.
    // Should be disabled in production/release builds.
    dat.Strict = false

    // Log any query over 10ms as warnings. (optional)
    runner.LogQueriesThreshold = 10 * time.Millisecond

    DB = runner.NewDB(db, "postgres")
}

type Post struct {
    ID        int64        `db:"id"`
    Title     string       `db:"title"`
    Body      string       `db:"body"`
    UserID    int64        `db:"user_id"`
    State     string       `db:"state"`
    UpdatedAt dat.NullTime `db:"updated_at"`
    CreatedAt dat.NullTime `db:"created_at"`
}

func main() {
    var post Post
    err := DB.
        Select("id, title").
        From("posts").
        Where("id = $1", 13).
        QueryStruct(&post)
    fmt.Println("Title", post.Title)
}
```

However, the script doesn't compile and I get the following error:

```
> go run main.go
go: finding github.com/mgutz/logxi latest
build command-line-arguments: cannot load github.com/mgutz/logxi: cannot find module providing package github.com/mgutz/logxi
```

This is probably because of the packages in that repo (https://github.com/mgutz/logxi) being located in the `v1` directory.

Is there any way I could fix this short of forking the `mgutz/dat` repo and fixing its dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there is `gopkg.in/mgutz/dat.v2` (not `v1`) which does work. Here is the modified script:

```golang
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "time"

    _ "github.com/lib/pq"

    "gopkg.in/mgutz/dat.v2/dat"
    runner "gopkg.in/mgutz/dat.v2/sqlx-runner"
)

// global database (pooling provided by SQL driver)
var DB *runner.DB

func init() {
    // create a normal database connection through database/sql
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "dbname=postgres user=postgres password=mypassword host=localhost sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // ensures the database can be pinged with an exponential backoff (15 min)
    runner.MustPing(db)

    // set to reasonable values for production
    db.SetMaxIdleConns(4)
    db.SetMaxOpenConns(16)

    // set this to enable interpolation
    dat.EnableInterpolation = true

    // set to check things like sessions closing.
    // Should be disabled in production/release builds.
    dat.Strict = false

    // Log any query over 10ms as warnings. (optional)
    runner.LogQueriesThreshold = 10 * time.Millisecond

    DB = runner.NewDB(db, "postgres")
}

type Post struct {
    ID        int64        `db:"id"`
    Title     string       `db:"title"`
    Body      string       `db:"body"`
    UserID    int64        `db:"user_id"`
    State     string       `db:"state"`
    UpdatedAt dat.NullTime `db:"updated_at"`
    CreatedAt dat.NullTime `db:"created_at"`
}

func main() {
    var post Post
    if err := DB.
        Select("id, title").
        From("posts").
        Where("id = $1", 13).
        QueryStruct(&post); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Title", post.Title)
}
```

To make the script run, I ran a Docker container like so:

```
docker run --name mypostgres -p "5432:5432" -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypassword -d postgres
```

connected to it using

```
psql --host=localhost --port=5432 --username=postgres --dbname=postgres
```

and entered the expected table and row:

```
postgres=# create table posts (id int, title varchar(50), body varchar(50), user_id int, state varchar(50), updated_at time, created_at time);
CREATE TABLE

postgres=# insert into posts (id, title, body, user_id, state, updated_at, created_at) values (13, 'My first post', 'Hello, world!', 1, 'CA', now(), now());
INSERT 0 1
```

Which prints the expected output:

```
> go run main.go
Title My first post
```